# How to use the comments icon for shopware 6

Tags: icons, shopware, shopware6

I tried to use the comments icon but seems that it does not exist.

This does not work:

```
<span class="questions-comments-icon">
   {% sw_icon 'comments' %}
</span>
```

This works:

```
<span class="social-share-icon">
    {% sw_icon 'share' %}
</span>
```

According to https://developer.shopware.com/resources/meteor-icon-kit/ the comments icon exists.
Maybe the name is wrong?

Comment: Look at /vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/dist/assets/icon/default if it exist

Answer (score 0):

Such an icon does not exist.

Check out the list here:
https://botschaft.digital/glossar/shopware-6-icons

Use `{% sw_icon 'speech-bubble' %}` instead.